salesforce restriction rules with custom permission
We have created a salesforce restriction rule on an object and have used a custom permission with boolean value as false condition to restrict records.
In the below screenshot we are setting the permission value as false. Basically for any user who is not assigned that custom permission through a permission set we want to restrict.
Unfortunately this doesnt work and it only works if we set the boolean value to true meaning anyone with the custom permission this restriction applies.

The documentation says this should work.
Any help if this is a bug or how to make this work will be much appreciated.
